# SQL.js Instead of creating a new sql database , access a file.sql

Tags: sqlite, sql.js

I need help (Problem inside code.)

````
 var db = new SQL.Database(); //instead of creating a new Database , i want to access one.
 db.run("CREATE TABLE todos (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, item TEXT);");```
````

Comment: Read the documentation for the sqlite bindings that you're using (sql.js?). There's presumably some way to tell it what database filename to use. If this is something run in a sandboxed environment like a web browser, you might be out of luck, though. Isn't there a javascript API for  safely accessing a persistent database in such a case?